# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Вот такая ошибка в android studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Вот build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chingiz.diplom"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev124-1.19.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.21.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
}
```

Подскажите что может быть?

Comment: нужно больше лога. Поищите в логе детальное сообщение от компилятора. Судя по кол-ву подключенных библиотек, вы могли вылезти за пределы 65535 методов в одном DEX-файле.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Это не обязательно именно ваш случай, но, глядя на количество `jar`-библиотек в вашем проекте, думаю, очень вероятный сценарий. Когда какие-то из зависимостей дублируют друг друга, при попытке компиляции появляется точь-в-точь такая же ошибка, как у вас.

Проверить, нет ли у вас дублируемых зависимостей можно открыв терминал в папке с проектом и прописав там команду `./gradlew имяпроекта:dependencies`.

[image: Результатом выполнения команды будет дерево зависимостей]

Оцените визуально это дерево на предмет повторяющихся зависимостей. Если они есть - ликвидируйте их и компилируйте заново.

В моей практике такое было, и справился с этой ошибкой именно этим путём.

**P.S.**
А ещё, чтобы логи при подобных ошибках были более развёрнутыми, зайдите в <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> -> <kbd>Build Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Compiler</kbd> и пропишите там в поле <kbd>Command-line Options</kbd> `--stacktrace`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я как бы поудалял, повторяющиеся зависимости, теперь таких ошибок 4)